# Is document/view architecture in MFC basically a Model/View/Controller pattern but without the controller?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, design-patterns, mfc

Is the document/view architecture in MFC really a Model/View/Controller pattern without the controller part?

I'm studying MFC and I simply love it to bits. I know is somewhat outdated and somewhat bit more difficult to use, but I discovered that it gives me so much more power and performance gain when compared to QT.

Am I correct to think of the MFC doc/view model as simply MVC without the Controller part?

Comment: The original "MVC" pattern has been completely superseded by modern (<= 20-25 years) GUI frameworks, which merge output and input components of the UI, eliminating the need or even possibility of an independent controller part. Unfortunately, the name "MVC" lives on and has been overloaded in the past decades. It's nowadays used by people for almost *any* architecture which separates UI and backend logic. It's not a useful term anymore, much like "object-oriented" or "agile". One purpose of a pattern is to give a concise name to a concrete idea. "MVC" does not meet this requirement anymore.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Excellent comment. Thanks. +1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a good fit for stackoverflow. It should be migrated to [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Model/View/Controler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) has the following components:

- Model
- View: responsible to show the model to the user
- Controller:  responsible to get user input and translate it in operations on the model

MFC's [Document/View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxcd8bht.aspx) has only 2 components:

- The document, which is in fact our model
- The View, which has the responsibility to show the Document AND [interpret the user's commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf3sesh8.aspx).  So it is the view+controller (refer to section *Variants* in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx))

Comment: Hi, thanks. So basically in Document/View pattern, View acts as a View and as a Controller, correct?

Comment: The Controller part is implemented by the CMainFrame which does the command routing. So, MFC can be compared with MVC with Model to Document, View to View and Controller to MainFrame window.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at it:

- The view contains UI code, both for rendering the data and for taking input from the user.
- The document contains the serialization code.

From that perspective, there's just a separation between UI and a backend. However, there's more, because you can have multiple different views on the same document. You could also use the document to just provide data storage and put any actual program logic into the view. In particular when you only effectively use a single view per document, it is easy to blur the separation in practice.

In summary, I wouldn't say the MVC controller part is missing but that it's merged with the MVC view parts into the MFC view.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. From your reply I gather that Document/View is inferior to MVC, because you can have actual logic in View, am I right?

Comment: A bad programmer can do stupid things in any language and with any framework.

Comment: yes, of course, but getting back to my question, am I right in saying that gathering info from your OR, that you see Document/View pattern inferior to MVC, because one can include logic in View part?

Comment: No. I wouldn't even know what the criteria are by which to call either approach "inferior" to the other. In practice, the bigger a program gets, the more important it is to have a clear structure for maintainability. Similarly, the smaller a program gets, the bigger the overhead grows that is caused by unnecessary structure.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that for larger programs you'd consider Document/View inferior to MVC, because as you've put it, a clear structure for maintability MVC provides?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: You try to simplify this question *way* too much. Designing the right software architecture for a given problem is harder than looking at the "size" of a program (how do you measure "size" anyway?) and then looking up the correct pattern.

Comment: ChristianHackl I'm not trying to simplify anything. Answer to my question was given by Christophe. The question I've asked @Ulrich was if MVC is more appropriate for larger applications, as he himself said and I quote: "In practice, the bigger a program gets, the more important it is to have a clear structure for maintainability." How do you measure bigger? Bigger than what? It was yesterday? Week ago? Bigger than other software of same usage? a) My question to Ulrich is clear, and b) you don't design architecture for a software when the software has any substantial size.

Comment: Yes, for large programs MVC might give advantages over MFC's document/view. This is a gut feeling and a vague description though, which you see yourself from the lack of a definition of "large". Further, if you compare frameworks like MFC and Qt, there are many other things that also have an impact. BTW: You asked how to "measure bigger", but you should also ask how to measure "clear structure"! I'm afraid this doesn't have any simple answers...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt yep, you are right in saying that it doesn't have simple answers. It simply confirms my feeling that MFC and its Document/View is as appropriate for 2015 applications like is QT's MVC. Whilst MFC gives so much more power and freedom compared to QT for example.

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: MFC's document/view architecture imposes a lot of restrictions. If you go with the pre-built architecture, you are sacrificing most of the freedom. The doc/view architecture was tailored for use in an MDI application. Neither one is in widespread use these days anymore. This does not imply, that MFC should not be used in new software, just that you need to carefully analyze, whether MFC's doc/view architecture is a good fit for your requirements. No simple answers here.

Comment: @IInspectable Hi, great to hear from you ;). Anyway, what kind of restrictions are we talking about when considering doc/view compared with for example QT's MVC?

Comment: @Thereisnothingwecando: I'm not aware, that Qt provides its own MVC framework. It is possible to implement the MVC pattern (whatever that is) using Qt, as much as you can with MFC. If you go with MFC's doc/view model, though, you'd best adhere to its rules. It works best, if you use doc templates, tied to specific view implementations. It also dictates, how messages and commands are routed. The doc/view model is best used with MFC's serialization, which in turn benefits from using MFC's container classes. Some of this can be customized, but not everything. Again, there are no simple answers.

Comment: @IInspectable, thanks, and yes, QT does provide its own MVC abstraction.

Comment: @IInspectable, as for adhering to MFC's rules... Isn't that with every framework? One simply have to obey their rules, otherwise it will either not work or you get UB. What I personally see had happened, lots of people jumped on the QT train because they couldn't/wouldn't appreciate MFC's power and flexibility, and they saw/thought of QT as a magical answer to easy UI programming. I don't see it that way. TBH the more I learn/use MFC the more I love it. And as I'm developing on Windows Desktop exclusively I would never go any other route than MFC.

Comment: @IInspectable To me with MFC and QT is bit like with people slagging Windows off and saying that Linux is much better. Yeah, my a**. Windows is the most professional OS, especially for people who want to make a living out of programming. I hope I will not start any OS war now, but in my personal experience I much prefer Windows to work with than linux. Other people may have different opinions/preferences and hey, that's cool too.

Comment: @IInspectable and others, I've just found out this gem: bcgsoft.com/samples/Visualization.htm it simply proves that MFC can create modern/contemporary looking apps. Without compromising performance. Sky is the limit. Win Desktop app? Only MFC!